# How to create a view based on taxonomy term of a node reference

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, nodes

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called "Sports" that lists out a number of sports terms (Football, Tennis, etc).

I have one content type called "Team". I have a "Sports" taxonomy term reference field set as I associate a sport to the team. The field is called **field_sport**.

I have another content type called "Fixture". It has a node reference to "Team". The field is called **field_sport_team**.

That is:

- a Fixture has a Team.
- a Team has a related Sport.

Question:

How can I create a view with a contextual filter based on a "Sports" term that returns all related "Fixture" given that the "Sports" term is associated to a "Team" node reference?

Been stuck over the past few days...

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: where do you want to display your view? On team page or on sports page?

Comment: Hi there. I would like to display it on sports page.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I've solved it myself!

I had to set up a relationship with "Team".

Then I added in a  "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" contextual filter. Within the settings there is a relationship option which I set to the one I set above.

Works as I expected!